# Bash script giving me a different result on reboot?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, reboot

I worked on a Bash script for the last day or so and running and debugging it directly on the shell.
The final script will be executed when the Ubuntu server gets rebooted. 
I have started testing this, but my script gives me a different result then what I was expected. 
I have narrowed it down to an "or condition" and rewrote a more simpler script to test this anomaly:

A call to this script has been made in /etc/rc.local, with a redirection of the output to a log file (log/reboot.log).

I have this in my script (as a test):

```
 #!/bin/bash 
YESTERDAY=20131103
SYS_DATE=20131104
LAST_START=20131104

if [[ $LAST_START = $YESTERDAY || $LAST_START = $SYS_DATE ]];
then
    echo "is equal"
else
   echo "is not equal"
fi
```

Executing in the shell I get "is equal" (the right answer). After the reboot in the log I get "is not equal".

Could someone tell me why?

Comment: I do not see any shebang line. Are you sure it is `bash` who runs the script with incorrect output?

Comment: Isn't `rc.local` executed by `sh`? Try to wrap everything in `bash` as: `bash -c 'YESTERDAY=20131103; SYS_DATE=20131104; if [[ $LAST_START = $YESTERDAY || $LAST_START = $SYS_DATE ]]; then echo "is equal"; else echo "is not equal"; fi'` and it should work.

Comment: What work was forcing the script to run in bash. So my script call in /etc/rc.local looks like: bash /mnt/ETLModule2/scripts/rs-reboot.sh /mnt/ETLModule2/ > /mnt/ETLModule2/log/reboot-date +'%s'.log Should I still continue developping in Bash or use a more standard POSIX way of scripting? Thanks for your help

Comment: For a trivial thing like this, restricting yourself to the POSIX repertoire is hardly a serious limitation.  If you find yourself longing for arrays etc, maybe consider switching to Bash after all (or a scripting language such as Python).

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing here,

But do you realize your `/bin/sh` is not your `SHELL`. 
In UBUNTU and Debian, `/bin/sh` is DASH, your login shell is BASH. 
So it might be related to your syntax of `[[ ]]` which is BASH.

Did you right in your top of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
```

> [[
>
> The [[ builtin is a bashism, and has somewhat better-defined semantics
>   than [ (a.k.a. test). However, it is still quite reasonable to use [
>   instead, and portable scripts must do so. Note that argument handling
>   is not quite the same; as above, use = rather than ==.

See here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh

#### the right way to do stuff here

The best solution would be actually to put your script in `/etc/init.d` and link it to run level 6. Which is the run level executed when rebooting. You should consider reading `man 8 init` when you have got some spare time. It will help you understand how your system is starting and shuting down.

Comment: Thanks for your help Oz123, forgot to mention on top of the script I have specified #!/bin/bash

Comment: @Alain, I added the shebang for you. Are you sure you are running in as BASH?

Comment: Good observation. But yes I have just checked it again.

Comment: could you elaborate more on "the /bin/sh is not your SHELL"? What is the difference between the system shell and the login shell?

Comment: @Alain, it is simple. The shell you use when you open a terminal is your login shell. In Debian and it's derivatives there was a decision that init script will be executed by DASH. For one reason because it is faster. For a second reason, it has a simpler syntax.